# Text file with existing file types?

Tags: shell, unix, text-files

Is there a text file out there that has all the common file types in it and grouped into "music", "documents", "videos", and so on?
I'd like to read it with a shell script and process files according to the class.

Comment: in unix/linux, you can also query a file for it's Unix type with `file myFile(.myExt)`. the `.myExt` will not affect the output of this command, `file` "peeks" at the first X bytes at the top of the file, and displays the associated type. `man file` may point  you to the file that it uses to make the associations. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah.. it is called MIME types

There is a list here.
http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/

See also this post [MIME Types Explained](http://www.howtogeek.com/192628/mime-types-explained-why-linux-and-mac-os-x-dont-need-file-extensions/).